# Useshuva Usefillah Utzedakah maavirin es roah hagezeira, where is this from?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, musaf, provenance

Does anyone know the history of how "Useshuvah Usefillah Utzedakah maavirin es roah hagezeirah" was put into our Tefillah and/or who wrote it? (It's in the chazaras hashatz for musaf on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kipur).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7423.

Comment: wasn't it in the unetaneh tokef *before* it was in chazarat hashatz?

Comment: I don't have the inside source, but according to an English language book on teshuva I'm reading, it says somewhere in the Bavli: "Four things will cause G-d to *ma'akirin* (tear up) the decree of judgment which has been issued against a person: acts of righteousness, fervent prayer, changing one's name and changing one's behavior."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yerushalmi Taanis Perek 2 Halacha 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47653&st=&pgnum=38)

אמר רבי לעזר: שלשה דברים מבטלין את הגזירה קשה ואילו הן: תפילה וצדקה ותשובה.

Comment: There still remains a question. Why did the composer, compose the words not in the order of the Yerushalmi?

Comment: and how did it turn from m'vatelin to maavirin?

Comment: the same quote is in [Bereshit Rabbah 44:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=37455&st=%u05D5%u05EA%u05E9%u05D5%u05D1%u05D4) which clearly came later based on the citation.

Comment: @GershonGold - Perhaps because Tefilah and Tzedakah are both included within Teshuvah?

Comment: @AdamMosheh - Then why did Rabbi Lezer say it differently?

Comment: I would like to propose that the order has to do with the time of the year. During Rosh HaShana and Yom Kippur when it is a time of Teshuva, it first says Teshuva, and when Rabbi Lezer said this it was during a regular time where Tefila came first.

Comment: See this answer for why the order is different: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20264/5151