# I got fired, is there a mitzvah I should do?

Tags: employment

I got fired from my job. The reason given was it was not working out. Besides seeking out a new job, is there anything I should do from a mitzvot standpoint?

Comment: Do more of them.

Comment: I know I’m late, but it’s a very big mitzvah to thank god for everything, especially things that are seemingly bad happen, because we know that everything Hashem does is the best thing for us, even though we sometimes can’t see it.

Answer (score 5):

You are obligated to make your best and most appropriate efforts to get yourself the income you need to fulfil your purpose. As an introduction read [this article](http://www.aishdas.org/rygb/bitachon.htm).

You also need to pray for your income as we learn from the first man. See [Braishis 2 (5) and Rashi’s commentary there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14361&st=&pgnum=26).

This is explained in this extract from [here](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5766/lech/oleitner3lch66.htm)

> The first time prayer is hinted at in the Torah is in (Bereishis 2:5).
>   The posuk writes: `And every tree of the field was not yet on the
>   earth and every herb of the field had not yet sprouted, for Hashem
>   Elokim had not sent rain to the earth and there was no man to work the
>   soil.'
>
> Rashi adds the following: `For what reason had He not sent
>    rain? Because there was no man to work the soil, and there was nobody
>    who would recognize the benefit of rain. When Odom realized that rain
>    was essential for the world, he prayed for it and it came down, so
>    that the trees and vegetation sprouted.'

May you be blessed with an easy parnassah.

Answer (score 4):

Do Teshuvah, Daven, and give Tzedakah.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18918/5

Answer (score -2):

No, there is no special thing. At least nothing I can consider.